# Dynamics SMTP details in laravel queue - SQS

Tags: laravel-5, queue

I am working on a Multi-tenant SaaS application where each organisation have separate databases and have their own SMTP details in database.

Now i am queuing all the bulk-emailing activity. Now the problem is how can i load the dynamic SMTP details for the laravel queue.

Currently my queue is working fine but its picking the default SMTP details from `.env` File

i even tried by setting changing Config details in mailable `_construct` method. But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

The mailer will be getting values from the config/mail.php class. Change the key values from the ENV function to a custom function which will then determine the correct SMTP details to use for the email.

Comment: Yes,i know that but again it will fail in the queue process

Answer (score 0):

Pass the email configuration settings as an argument when the job is pushed to the queue, so that the job has access to the correct settings at the time of execution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).